# Repeat subheadings Latex longtable

Tags: longtable

I am producing listings of demographics for a statistical report. We have headings on each table that indicate the types of subjects accounted for (say, treated versus control). Then the table has subheadings like Age, Sex, Race vertically with indented rows showing formatted levels and counts for each of these values.

Race is a particularly long subheading, so as the page breaks, we see again the display of the treated / control heading, but the race listing continues without any label for the subheading. How do I get Latex to list the heading and the subheading on the next page (where the subheading changes throughout the table)?

Here is the existing tex file (deidentified)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize

\begin{center}

\begin{longtable}{lrrrrrr}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{ Mastectomy }      \\ (N =  XX ) \end{tabular}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{ Other therapies } \\ (N =  XX ) \end{tabular}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{ Total }           \\ (N =  XX ) \end{tabular}} \endhead \\ 
\textbf{Diagnosis}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} Under XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX+ years & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{MaritalStatus}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} single & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} not married but have a significant other & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} married & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} separated & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} divorced & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} widowed & X & (XX.X) & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Education}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} less than high school & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} high school/GED & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} some college & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} college degree: associates & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} college degree: bachelors & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} masters degree & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} doctorate degree & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{EmployStatus}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} employed, part time & X & (X.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} employed, full time & XX & (XX.X) & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unemployed & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} retired & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Hispanic}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} yes & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} no & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Race}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} white & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} black or african american & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} asian & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} native hawaiian/other pacific islander & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} american indian or alaska native & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} other & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Religion}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} protestant christian & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} roman catholic & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} evangelical christian & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} jewish & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} muslim & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} hindu & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} buddist & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} other & X & (XX.X) & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Help}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} yes & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} no & XX & (XXX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{ruca}; mean (sd) & X.X & (X.X) & X.X & (X.X) & X.X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} \textit{missing}; n [\%] & X & [X.X] & X & [X.X] & X & [X.X] \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: without a complete example document showing the problem (every question should have a complete test document) it is hard to say, but if you mean what I think you mean the answer might be that it is hard to do automatically in longtable, LT really assumes a fixed (but repeating) header and doesn't make it easy to change the header or add rows dynamically.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I included the tex file, but you have described the problem I am getting at. That's unfortunate.

Comment: it's not actually runnable in latex as it is 9Ive used longtable before and could guess, but I can't guess your page size etc. also `center` doesn't do anything to lonngtable other than add some spurious vertical space

Comment: `\multicolumn{X}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry, deidentified I replaced [0-9] with X and accidentally missed some formatting. This should be entirely cut-and-paste ready

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite right

```
 Overfull \hbox (0.13614pt too wide) in alignment at lines 109--113
```

but it's digging in some very old code:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-40pt}
\addtolength\textwidth{80pt}
\makeatletter
\def\LT@output{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
      \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
      \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
      \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
          \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
          \@makecol
          \@outputpage
          \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
        \fi
      \fi
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \global\vsize\@colht
      \vbox
        {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
    \fi
  \else
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
    \@makecol
    \@outputpage
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \copy\LT@head\nobreak
\LT@bchunk\rlap{\currentheading\ (continued)}\LT@echunk
\unvbox\z@
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\footnotesize



\begin{longtable}{lrrrrrr}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{ Mastectomy }      \\ (N =  XX ) \end{tabular}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{ Other therapies } \\ (N =  XX ) \end{tabular}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \begin{tabular}{c} \textbf{ Total }           \\ (N =  XX ) \end{tabular}} \endhead \\ 
\textbf{Diagnosis}; n (\%) \gdef\currentheading{\textbf{Diagnosis}} &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} Under XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX-XX years & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} XX+ years & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{MaritalStatus}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} single & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} not married but have a significant other & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} married & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} separated & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} divorced & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} widowed & X & (XX.X) & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Education}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} less than high school & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} high school/GED & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} some college & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} college degree: associates & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} college degree: bachelors & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} masters degree & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} doctorate degree & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{EmployStatus}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} employed, part time & X & (X.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} employed, full time & XX & (XX.X) & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unemployed & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} retired & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Hispanic}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} yes & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} no & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Race}; n (\%) \gdef\currentheading{\textbf{Race}} &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} white & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} black or african american & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} asian & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} native hawaiian/other pacific islander & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} american indian or alaska native & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} other & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Religion}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} protestant christian & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} roman catholic & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} evangelical christian & X & (XX.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} jewish & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} muslim & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} hindu & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} buddist & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} other & X & (XX.X) & X & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{Help}; n (\%) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hspace{3mm} yes & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} no & XX & (XXX.X) & XX & (XX.X) & XX & (XX.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} unanswered & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) & X & (X.X) \\
\textbf{ruca}; mean (sd) & X.X & (X.X) & X.X & (X.X) & X.X & (X.X) \\
\hspace{3mm} \textit{missing}; n [\%] & X & [X.X] & X & [X.X] & X & [X.X] \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Haha thank you for pointing that out. Coincidentally, a second round of building the pdf usually corrects the indenting. I didn't know longtable does not allow for indenting, it's such a critical part of building tables as it helps to display subheadings (the crux of the issue at hand).